# Radius search with latitude and longitude with sql query

Tags: sql

In the query below, what is "cos( radians( lat )" or "cos( radians( lng ) or "radians( lat )"? What exactly does the radians() function do?

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) 
               * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
               * cos( radians( lng ) 
               - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) 
               * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM markers 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_radians

Answer (score 2):

The circular functions here (`cos()`, `sin()`) take angles in radians (2*Pi radians in a circle), but the angles are given in degrees (360 degrees in a circle), so the `Radians()` function converts Degrees to Radians so that the circular functions will give the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CurrentLocation geography; 
SET @CurrentLocation  = geography::Point(12.822222, 80.222222, 4326)

SELECT * , Round (GeoLocation.STDistance(@CurrentLocation ),0) AS Distance FROM [Landmark]
WHERE GeoLocation.STDistance(@CurrentLocation )<= 2000 -- 2 Km
```

Wonderful Tutorial:

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/convert-latitude-longitude-to-geography-point.aspx